# How can I connect to Memgraph database and executes queries using Rust?

Tags: rust, memgraphdb

I'm starting to learn Rust. I want to try out connecting to the Memgraph database and executing a query. I'm running a local instance of Memgraph Platform in Docker. I'm running it with default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Docker right after you create a new Rust project using `cargo new memgraph_rust --bin` add the following line to the `Cargo.toml` file under the line `[dependencies]` :

```
rsmgclient = "1.0.0"
```

Then, add the following code to the src/main.rs file:

```
use rsmgclient::{ConnectParams, Connection, SSLMode};

fn main(){
    // Parameters for connecting to database.
    let connect_params = ConnectParams {
        host: Some(String::from("172.17.0.2")),
        sslmode: SSLMode::Disable,
        ..Default::default()
    };

    // Make a connection to the database.
    let mut connection = match Connection::connect(&connect_params) {
        Ok(c) => c,
        Err(err) => panic!("{}", err)
    };

    // Execute a query.
    let query = "CREATE (u:User {name: 'Alice'})-[:Likes]->(m:Software {name: 'Memgraph'}) RETURN u, m";
    match connection.execute(query, None) {
        Ok(columns) => println!("Columns: {}", columns.join(", ")),
        Err(err) => panic!("{}", err)
    };

    // Fetch all query results.
    match connection.fetchall() {
        Ok(records) => {
            for value in &records[0].values {
                println!("{}", value);
            }
        },
        Err(err) => panic!("{}", err)
    };

    // Commit any pending transaction to the database.
    match connection.commit() {
        Ok(()) => {},
        Err(err) => panic!("{}", err)
    };
}
```

Now, create a new file in the project root directory /memgraph_rust and name it Dockerfile:

```
# Set base image (host OS)
FROM rust:1.56

# Install CMake
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get --yes install cmake

# Install mgclient
RUN apt-get install -y git cmake make gcc g++ libssl-dev clang && \
  git clone https://github.com/memgraph/mgclient.git /mgclient && \
  cd mgclient && \
  git checkout 5ae69ea4774e9b525a2be0c9fc25fb83490f13bb && \
  mkdir build && \
  cd build && \
  cmake .. && \
  make && \
  make install

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /code

# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY Cargo.toml .

# Copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
RUN mkdir src
COPY src/ ./src

# Generate binary using the Rust compiler
RUN cargo build

# Command to run on container start
CMD [ "cargo", "run" ]
```

All that is now left is to get the address `docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' CONTAINER_ID`, create and image `docker build -t memgraph_rust .` and starting the application with `docker run memgraph_rust`.

If you ever decide to take your Rust program to an environment that doesn't have Docker you will maybe need to install [`rsmgclient` driver](https://github.com/memgraph/rsmgclient)

The complete documentation for connecting using Rust can be found at [Rust quick start guide](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/rust) on the Memgraph site.